# Problems with compilation ICU with MinGW-w64 on Windows

Tags: windows, mingw, icu, msys2

I tried to compile ICU 59.1 with MinGW-w64 according to Qt manual ([MinGW-64-bit](https://wiki.qt.io/MinGW-64-bit)). Unfortunately, I got the following error:

```
$ make && make install
rebuilding config/icucross.mk
rebuilding config/icucross.inc
cd ./config; \
        make -f pkgdataMakefile
make[1]: вход в каталог «/c/Qt-deps/icu-59_1/source/config»


*** ERROR - configure could not detect your platform
*** see the readme.html
*** or, try copying icu/source/config/mh-linux to mh-unknown
***   and editing it.


exit 1
rm -rf pkgdata.inc
make[1]: выход из каталога «/c/Qt-deps/icu-59_1/source/config»
rm -rf config/icu-config
/usr/bin/install -c ./config/icu-config-top config/icu-config
chmod u+w config/icu-config
LC_ALL=C /usr/bin/sed -f ./config/make2sh.sed < ./config/Makefile.inc | grep -v '#M#' | uniq >> config/icu-config
LC_ALL=C /usr/bin/sed -f ./config/make2sh.sed < ./config/mh-unknown | grep -v '#M#' | uniq >> config/icu-config
cat ./config/icu-config-bottom >> config/icu-config
chmod u-w config/icu-config
config/icu-uc.pc updated.
config/icu-i18n.pc updated.
config/icu-io.pc updated.
Note: rebuild with "make VERBOSE=1 " to show all compiler parameters.
/bin/sh ./mkinstalldirs lib
mkdir lib
/bin/sh ./mkinstalldirs bin
mkdir bin
make[0]: Making `all' in `stubdata'
make[1]: вход в каталог «/c/Qt-deps/icu-59_1/source/stubdata»


*** ERROR - configure could not detect your platform
*** see the readme.html
*** or, try copying icu/source/config/mh-linux to mh-unknown
***   and editing it.


exit 1
make[1]: выход из каталога «/c/Qt-deps/icu-59_1/source/stubdata»
make: *** [Makefile:147: all-recursive] Ошибка 2
```

I have tried to compile it twice on two different computers: the 1st one - Windows 10 Pro, the last one - Windows 7 Ultimate. Results are the same. Used tools: MSYS2 x64 (20161025). So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is already a [mingw-w64 ICU package](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/tree/master/mingw-w64-icu) for MSYS2.  The maintainers of MSYS2 have spent time adjusting the build scripts and adding patches to make it work.  Is there any reason for you to compile this on your own instead of just installing the binary MSYS2 package?

Comment: @DavidGrayson Yes, I have to do this, because I need ICU for compiling Qt

Comment: That doesn't make much sense.  You can disable the ICU dependency Qt has with `-no-icu` (I've done that myself in [nixcrpkgs](https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/nixcrpkgs)).  You could use the MSYS2 ICU package to compile your own Qt if you really want a version of Qt that depends on ICU.  Or you could just use the MSYS2 package for Qt and not compile anything.  Anyway, if you really know that you need to compile ICU from source, you should probably use the PKGBUILD script I linked to as a starting point; it can be built with `makepkg-mingw`.

Answer (score 2):

The error "configure could not detect your platform" can probably be fixed by passing the arguments `--build=$MINGW_CHOST --host=$MINGW_CHOST` to the configure script.  If you are in the right type of MSYS2 shell, `$MINGW_CHOST` should be `i686-w64-mingw32` or `x86_64-w64-mingw32`

For more useful tips for building ICU, look at the build script that the MSYS2 developers have crafted:

https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/tree/master/mingw-w64-icu

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the same issue (except that used ICU 55.1) replacing *../source/config/mh-unknown* with the contents of *../source/config/mh-mingw64*

Answer (score 1):

I have build icu with same problem.
I have run this script for correct the problem:

```
del M:\work\code\qt\icu4c-68_2\icu4c\source\config\mh-unknow
copy M:\work\code\qt\icu4c-68_2\icu4c\source\config\mh-msys-msvc M:\work\code\qt\icu4c-68_2\icu4c\source\config\mh-unknow
```